# find s string patterns in html code in c#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I want to create a robot to find news in my defined website, so my robot fetch the html code from the website and I should find the news part of the html code. For example one of the pattern that I should find is like this :

```
<li><a href="/news?p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_mode=news&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_newsId=3206056&p_p_state=maximized">بازدید رئیس هیئت عامل صندوق نوآوری و شکوفایی از خبرگزاری مهر</a></li>
```

I want to know how can I find these pattern in the html code in C#. I googled it and i found something like `regular expression`.
But in regular expression I can't define patterns. Can I define some pattern like this? With this complexity?

Comment: Do not parse html/xml with a regex. Use a library. Regexes cannot parse hml/xml...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem which kind of library ?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is the standard.

Comment: [obligatory reference on html vs. regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590)

Comment: It could be done in multiple ways. first find the tags. then you parse them individualy. and by gaining experience you will define allot cases for each urls.